# Wordpress migration issue- links/media

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, media, migrate

I have been migrating from server to localhost and all of my links and  paths are broken, except for few. The problem is really strange. My config files have these lines added:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://localhost/barlet');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost/barlet');
```

But it does not solve any problem, any links still looks like this:

```
http://localhost/wp-content/themes/aquablock/images/portfolio_o.jpg
```

Why and how it does not have the /barlet in after localhost I HAVE NO IDEA. Tried many things and im not new to wordpress and migrations, but this has been a big pain. Also it might be that the site is multisite so maybe that is the issue but still..?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this can be avoided if you override the path where Wordpress looks for your assets, e.g. [moving the wp-content folder](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_wp-content_folder).

In short, try adding the following to your wp-config.php:

```php
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/barlet' ); 
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://your-full-url.com/barlet');
```

This will force Wordpress to look for the assets in the specified paths e.g. fqdn.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem still stays.. Added the following::

define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/barlet' ); 
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://localhost/barlet');

Comment: its added its just that stackoveflow does not write it here, it makes it a hyperlink because of that.

Comment: In that case, you can verify two things: 
1. Look at the earlier mentioned link to the WP Codex for other path overrides (like the PLUGINS, for example)
2. Make sure your theme (aquablock?) doesn't have any hardcoded references to url's in it. E.g. look through the .php files and see if it uses the WP_CONTENT_DIR properly, instead of '/wp-content/themes/whatever'.

Comment: Not the admin panel, but the .php files: are there any hardcoded references in there?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33022/discussion-between-rokas-petrosius-and-moriarty)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem as following:

First of all it had nothing to do with wordpress itself, but with apache and vhosts.

I opened file: xammp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

and added following lines:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/barlet/"
    ServerName barlet.local
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I added this line to my hosts file(windir/system32/drivers/etc/hosts):

```
127.0.0.1 barlet.local
```

This was the solution for me, hope it helps anyone!